# Website run slower when run first time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, web

I have a website built by Node.js. The first time you run a website in any browser, it is very slow compared to the next run. So how to fix the situation above?

Comment: If the browser doesn't have a local copy of the static files used by your site, it will download them. Next time it won't have to because they will be stored in the browser's cache.

Comment: As advised, this is 'normal',... you need to apply some compression and other methods to speed this up.. If you are using PHP, one simple trick is to use gzip compression... Otherwise a little googling on speeding up websites will go over all these steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal, its not an issue/bug as such..

Basically first time around you are running without any cache and your browser has to download everything and store it.. Second time around it loads certain content from your browsers cache and hence does not need to be downloaded again.

The trick here is to make sure the initial download is as small as possible and that you do not have any blocking scripts.

Things to check / fix here would be... Making sure your have your javascript use the DOM ready event correctly. Also having in general smaller js/css files will also help as the download time will be quicker..

Basically... Compression, Check Any Blocking Scripts (long loading scripts in your head tag).. These should be moved to just below your closing body tag.

For this purpose, there are plenty of websites and methods you can use to strip excess content from your files, or compress them by renaming variables to shorter names and removing blank lines and so on.. Simply you want the smallest possible files and make sure they are loaded in the order they are needed.

**BLOCKING SCRIPTS / RESOURCES**

If you have a JS file that sits at the top of your page / near the HEAD of your page.. Your browser waits for this to be loaded / downloaded before it continues loading the page.  So if you move this to the bottom of your page, it will load your HTML/ visual content first and then load the script last ... Hence giving the impression of a quicker loading page.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the first time you load your website on a browser, javascript, images, and css files have to be loaded. After they are loaded once, your browser caches them so on the next reload, your browser sees it needs those files, and then sees that it already has them so it doesn't download them again.